# ThreeJS: native Antialias not working with Outline postprocessing effect

Tags: three.js, antialiasing, post-processing

I'm working on a project that uses a lot of lines and marks with the camera at a very low angle (almost at ground level). I'm also using an outline effect to highlight selected objects in different ways (selection, collisions, etc.).

Native AA is lost when using postprocessing effects (eg: outline effect). This causes jagged lines on screen, more noticeable when the camera is closer to ground level.

I have created this jsFiddle to illustrate the issue (using ThreeJS r111):

https://jsfiddle.net/Eketol/s143behw/

Just press mouse/touch the 3D scene to render without postprocessing effects and release mouse/touch to render with it again.

[image: ThreeJS - Issue - Antialias with Outline effect]

Some posts suggest using an FXAAShader pass will solve it, but I haven't had any luck with it. Instead, I get some artifacts on the scene and in some cases the whole image is broken.

So far my options are:

- Get a workaround to get the outline effects without postprocessing effects:
  The ones I've seen around (eg: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html) duplicate the meshes/geometries to render a bigger version with a solid color applied behind the main object. While it may be ok with basic static geometries like a cube, it doesn't seem an efficient solution when using complex 3D objects that you need to drag around (objects with multiple meshes).
- Increasing the `renderer.pixelratio` value to get a bigger frame size: This is not an option for me. On my test it doesn't make a big difference and also makes the rendering slower.
- Try to get FXAAShader working without artifacts: As I said, it doesn't seem to fix the issue as well as the native AA does (and it is not as compatible). Maybe I'm not using it correctly, but I just get antialiased jagged lines.

Question 1: It may sound silly, but I though there would be an easy way to send the antialiased image directly to the composer or at least there could be some extra pass to do this, keeping the native AA. Is this possible?

Question 2: Maybe using `Scene.onAfterRender` to get the image with native AA and then blending the outline effect somehow?

Question 3: Googling around, it seems this issue also affects to Unity. In [this post](https://github.com/openworm/org.geppetto.frontend/issues/724#issuecomment-355576308), it says this won't be an problem with WebGL2. Does this also apply to ThreeJS?

Comment: You are correct on all counts.